# Look-ups in Redux Reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux

Let's say I have the following state:

```
state =  {
  products: {
    50: {
      sku: "000",
      name: "A Product",
      category: 123,
      ...
    }
  },
  categories: {
    123: {
      name: "Some Category",
      parentCategory: 100,
      department: "Electronics"
    }  
  },
  filteredProducts: [50] 
}
```

I want to be able to filter products based on categories. However, I need to filter based on multiple properties of categories. i.e. I might want to get all categories within the Electronics department or I might want to get a category with id 123 and all it's sub-categories.

This is a bit of a contrived example that closely matches what I'm trying to achieve but it's a bit easier to understand, so please bear with me. I'm aware that in this specific instance, I could probably use something like reselect, but assuming that I needed to do a category lookup for a products reducer, what would my options be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reselect` as you mentioned, and make some selectors with parameter the re-use these selectors from categories in products to be as follow:

Make your `category/selectors` file as follow:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const categoriesSelector = state => state.categories;

const selectCategoryById = id => {
  return createSelector(
    categoriesSelector,
    categories => categories[id]
  );
}

const selectCategoryByName = name => {
  return createSelector(
    categoriesSelector,
    categories => categories.filter(c => c.name === name)
  );
}

export default {
  categoriesSelector,
  selectCategoryById,
  selectCategoryByName,
}
```

Meanwhile, in `product/selector` you can import both **category** and **product** selector files as follow:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { selectCategoryById } from './category/selectors';

const productsSelector = state => state.products;

const selectProductByCategoryId = id => {
  return createSelector(
    productsSelector,
    selectCategoryById,
    (products, categories) => products.filter(p.category.indexOf(id) > -1)
  );
}

export default {
  productsSelector,
  selectProductByCategoryId,
}
```

And in `product/reducer`, you can import both selectors and return the new changed state based on category logic.

Comment: I won't have access to the whole state in my products reducer, though? I'll only have access to the products state object.

Comment: Mmm, right! So in this case i think you can do the filter logic on component may be in `componentWillReceiveProps` right after `FETCH_ALL_PRODUCTS` method is dispatched (not sure if this is the best practice or not). Or if you can have access/maintain your backend by adding an endpoint that filter server-side `GET` `/products/:categoryId`.